# Cloning from Github failed

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea

just tried to clone a project from github in intellij idea.

Unfortunately i get the following exception (roughly translated from german to english):

*The procedure entry point "curl_global_sslset" could not be found in the dll "E:\programs\git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-remote-https.exe".*

Any ideas, why that happens?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of broken installation. E.g. [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/SourceTree-questions/git-remote-https-exe-libcurl-4-dll-The-procedure-entry-point-SSL/qaq-p/427587) is a similar issue.
You could try reinstalling Git for windows.

Does it work from the command line, btw? What git executable is configured in Settings - Version control - Git in IDEA? Make sure it is the same as the one returned by the `where git` command